# How do I use _vsnprintf_r() correctly?

Tags: c++, c, windows, cygwin, reentrancy

I am trying to learn something about re-entrant calls and I am trying to use `_vsnprintf_r()`. The first parameter seems to be some `struct _reent *`. On Cygwin, it seems that I could just use it like this: `_vsnprintf_r (_REENT, /* rest of the arguments here */)`. Is this correct? Is this correct even outside Cygwin? There seems to be certain lack of documentation for this. My Google and Bing searches were not too fruitful.

Comment: That function probably doesn't exist on any other platform. A leading `_` is usually a sign that says "don't touch me unless you're hacking the C library itself".

Comment: This is not a way to "learn about reentrant calls". It's a way to learn about ugly implementation internals of cygwin. If you're thinking of writing an implementation of the standard library, it could be educational to read cygwin source (probably as an idea of what **not** to do in writing your own), but if you just want to learn about writing reentrant code, it's trivially simple: don't use any non-const static/global variables.

Comment: Has vsnprintf been known to ever have a rentrant version?  It would mean that it is modifying a common resource (the dest character array).  Calls to vsnprintf are between va_start()  and va_end(). A related thread of discussion :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3865713/is-va-start-etc-reentrant

Answer (score 2):

`_vsnprintf_r` is not a standard function. It was created by the cygwin development team for internal use.

The `_vsnprintf_r` is called by the regular `vsnprintf`, so I would stick with using the regular `C` version of this call on cygwin. There is no guarantee from cygwin that the `_vsnprintf_r` is reentrant anyway, especially if you cannot locate any documentation about it.

Since cygwin uses a dynamically loaded library that has shared state among all processes that link against it, it uses the `_<xxx>_r` versions of the calls to give each process its own instances of state that would normally be the default on a standard UNIX system. Since these functions are used by cygwin internally, you may find the [cygwin-developers mailing list](http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin-developers/) a better resource for your question.

This is in contrast to reentrant functions defined by POSIX (like `gmtime_r`). The non-reentrant versions of those returned pointers to static memory within the library, so reentrant versions were created to allow the function to use memory passed in by the caller instead.

Comment: Assume that I have reasons not to use the non `_r` version.

Comment: @wilx: Fair enough! I have edited the answer suggesting the cygwin-developers mailing list as a better resource. Thanks and regards.

Answer (score -1):

You probably don't want to "print" anything with re-entrant calls, cause you don't know what order or when things will be "printing".

In general terms, to write re-entrant functions, pass everything into the function (no static variables).  Local (stack) variables are okay AFAIK.

Printing is a "classic" problem for semaphores (or some other locking mechanism).  Otherwise,

Hello
World

becomes

HeWlorllod

or at best

HellWorldo

Comment: Reentrancy is something slightly different than concurrency with threads.